# Evitar Warning: POST Content-Length al subir archivo

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de subir un archivo con **PHP**, estoy usando lo básico según la documentación del [PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="carga.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" />
    Subir archivo: <input name="archivo" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar fichero" />
</form>
```

Y en el php tengo:

```
$ruta = APP_BASEDIR . "/cargas/";
$fichero_subido = $ruta . basename($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $fichero_subido)) {
    echo "El fichero es válido y se subió con éxito.\n";
} else {
    echo "¡Posible ataque de subida de ficheros!\n";
}
```

Pero cuando trato de subir un archivo demasiado grande me muestra: ***Warning: POST Content-Length of 83316897 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0***

Pero no marca ninguna línea de código.
El archivo que quiero subir no pesa ni 1Mb. No excede los límites predeterminados del php.ini que son 2Mb, por eso no modifiqué nada.
Pero quiero que el código capture el error en caso el archivo sea demasiado pesado. Pero cómo puedo capturar el error de la carga si no me indica dónde está?
Incluso agregué

```
echo "Tamaño ".$_FILES['archivo']['size'];
```

Pero no muestra nada.
La consola muestra este mensaje unos segundos y luego se limpia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81495/discussion-on-question-by-piropeator-evitar-warning-post-content-length-al-subi).

Comment: Hola @Piropeador , ¿la respuesta que redacté se ajusta más a tus necesidades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso del campo del formulario `MAX_FILE_SIZE` se usa para limitar el tamaño de los archivos en el lado del servidor, cuando los datos han sido enviados. Es decir, no se comprueba dicho tamaño previo al envío, por lo que no evitarás que salga la advertencia si superas el máximo permitido por PHP (por defecto, 8 MiB).

Para comprobar el tamaño y cancelar el envío debes usar una comprobación desde el lado del cliente mediante el uso del [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileList) que está disponible en HTML5 en los campos [`<input type="file" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Cada elemento de `FileList` es una instancia de [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File) que tiene las siguientes propiedades (incluyendo las heredadas de [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob)):

> **File.lastModifiedDate**
>
> La última `Date(fecha)` de modificación del archivo referenciado por el objeto `File`.
>
> **File.name**
>
> El nombre del archivo referenciado por el objeto `File`.
>
> **File.fileName** (Obsoleto Gecko 7.0)
>
> El nombre del archivo referenciado por el objeto `File`.
>
> **File.fileSize** (Obsoleto Gecko 7.0)
>
> El tamaño del archivo referenciado en bytes.
>
> **Blob.size**
>
> El tamaño, en bytes, de los datos contenidos en el objeto `Blob`.
>
> **Blob.type**
>
> Una cadena (`String`) indicando el tipo MIME de los datos contenidos en el `Blob`. Si el tipo es desconocido, esta cadena será vacía.

De modo que con la siguientes líneas podrías comprobar si el tamaño del único archivo que tienes en tu formulario es superior al marcado por la etiqueta:

```
let archivo = form.querySelector('input[name="archivo"]').files[0].size;
let maximo = form.querySelector('input[name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"]').value;
if (archivo > maximo) {
  alert('Máximo superado');
}
```

Puedes agregar esa comprobación en el evento de envío del formulario para evitar que envíen archivos más grandes del límite o bien en el evento de cambio.

Aquí tienes una prueba de concepto que comprueba tanto el tamaño individual de cada archivo del formulario como el total de éste:

```
<?php
if (count($_FILES) > 0) {
    $ruta = __DIR__ . "/cargas/";
    $fichero_subido = $ruta . basename($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $fichero_subido)) {
        echo "El fichero es válido y se subió con éxito.\n";
    } else {
        echo "¡Posible ataque de subida de ficheros!\n";
    }
}
?><form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="carga.php"
  method="POST" onsubmit="return comprobar(this)">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" />
    Subir archivo: <input name="archivo" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar fichero" />
</form>
<script>
function comprobar(form) {
    let maximo = form.querySelector('input[name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"]'), total = 0;
    /* Si no está la etiqueta MAX_FILE_SIZE
      creamos un máximo por defecto */
    if (maximo === null) {
        maximo = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        console.log('Máximo (por defecto):', maximo);
    } else {
        maximo = parseInt(maximo.value);
        console.log('Máximo (etiqueta):', maximo);
    }
    let fallidos = [], compatible = true;
    /* Comprobamos cada archivo del formulario */
    form.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]').forEach(function(archivos) {
        /* Si está disponible en el navegador, hacemos uso de FileList/File
            para comprobar el tamaño de los archivos */
        if (archivos.files) {
            for (let i = 0; i < archivos.files.length; i++) {
                /* Actualizamos el total del formulario completo
                  (si hay varios archivos) */
                total += archivos.files[i].size;
                if (archivos.files[i].size > maximo) {
                    fallidos.push(archivos.files[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            /* Marcamos la compatibilidad como fallida */
            compatible = false;
        }
    });
    /* Comprobamos la compatibilidad con HTML5 */
    if (compatible === false) {
        console.log(
            'ADVERTENCIA: Su navegador no es compatible con HTML5.',
            'No se comprobará el tamaño de los archivos.'
        );
        /* Aún así permitimos el envío del formulario, saldrá
          la advertencia de PHP si se supera el máximo */
        return true;
    }
    /* Si no ha sido rechazado ningún archivo y el total está
      en el margen establecido, enviamos el formulario */
    if (fallidos.length == 0 && total <= maximo) {
        console.log('Todos los tamaños están en márgenes correctos');
        return true;
    } else {
        let mensaje = '';
        if (fallidos.length > 0) {
            mensaje = 'Los siguientes archivos superan el máximo:\n';
            fallidos.forEach(function(archivo){
                mensaje += '- "' + archivo.name + '" ('
                  + parseInt(archivo.size / 1024) + ' KiB)\n';
            });
        } else if (total > maximo) {
            mensaje += 'El máximo total ha sido superado ('
              + parseInt(total / 1024) + ' KiB)';
        }
        console.log(mensaje);
        alert(mensaje);
    }
    /* Si hemos llegado a este punto debemos cancelar el envío */
    return false;
}
</script>
```

---

NOTA: Debes saber que el API `File` de HTML5 está disponible en los navegadores actuales, [estando obsoletos las siguientes versiones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob#Browser_compatibility) (soporte básico / soporte completo):

- Internet Explorer < 10
- Google Chrome < 5/21
- Firefox < 4/13
- Opera < 11.10/12.10
- Safari < 5.1/6

En navegadores sin soporte el envío se efectuará, apareciendo la advertencia de PHP de límite superado.

Mi respuesta anterior [queda guardada aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/187759/3).

Comment: Interesante respuesta. Pero no quiero cambiar nada en el archivo php.ini porque no necesito cargar archivos tan pesados. Solamente estaba probando las validaciones en PHP hasta que me encontré con este caso. Por eso quería validar desde PHP el supuesto que el usuario trate de cargar un archivo extremadamente grande.

Comment: No te he propuesto cambiar el `php.ini` de manera definitiva, sólo para probar qué se está enviando (para que PHP no lo corte). ¿Podrías mirar la consola de depuración (inspector de red) para ver qué se está enviando por POST al servidor?

Comment: Agregué la consola en la pregunta.

Comment: Veo que usas Google Chrome. En ese caso para hacer lo que te pido debes ir a la pestaña "Network" y allí marcar "Preserve log" (te será útil mantener el log en todas las pestañas para que no desaparezca al cargar una nueva página como te está pasando). En esa pestaña pulsa en la petición POST y entonces usa la pestaña "Headers" para comprobar en "Query String Parameters" lo que se ha enviado al servidor. Como has activado la opción de mantener el log no desparecerá y podrás usar "copiar/pegar" para mostrarme su contenido. Mira también la cabecera `Content-Length` como puse en mi respuesta.

Comment: Esto muestra al ejecutar el upload:
Content-Length: 89579991
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryghLt5QnfnToLfF69
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/Varios/upload.html
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Comment: Pon la información como edición en tu pregunta o vayamos a un chat. Como comentario se corta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81509/discussion-between-piropeator-and-oscargarcia).